# How to preprocess data for tensorflow/serving model?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm relatively new to Tensorflow. I have this model deployed locally, using Docker but the data I'm inputting is not preprocessed so it gives me an error. This might be due to the fact that I preprocessed the data outside the model when creating the model?

When I input the data, I get this error from the deployed tensorflow/serving through Docker:

```
{ "error": "Failed to process element: 0 of \'instances\' list. Error: Invalid argument: JSON Value: \"Hello\" Type: String is not of expected type: float" }
```

Meaning it expects an array of tokenized words so, [[32],[1]]. Something like that.

**This is what my model looks like:**

```
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
                vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=max_length),
            tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax")
        ])
```

How can I tokenize and pad the data the same way I did with the initial training data or how can I add that step to the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

After a long time searching for the answer, I don't know why it took so long for me to come across pickling, the answer to tokenizing the input request with the same tokenizer would be to pickle, so

```
# saving
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# loading
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    tokenizer = pickle.load(handle)
```

Same can be done with the padding if needed.